# Exit from an if [Python]

Tags: python, audio, amixer

I can't exit from this if construct

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import os
import re
import time
global state


#print status_on.group()
def main():
    get_current_jack_status = """amixer -c1 contents | grep -A 2 'Headphone Jack'"""
    output = os.popen(get_current_jack_status).read()
    status_on = re.search('values=on', output)
    if status_on:
        state = status_on
        os.system("notify-send 'Audio Manager' 'An audio jack was plugged in' -i audacity.png")
        if status_on == state:
            print "True"
            state = 1   #here i can't exit

        if status_on != state:
            print state
            os.system("notify-send 'Audio Manager' 'An audio jack was unplugged' -i audacity.png")


while True:
    main()
```

I've tried pass but when I execute the script it says as output:

```
True
1
True
1
```

ecc.
If I use "break" it crashes.

Comment: If you have a `break` where?

Comment: What is the purpose of `while True: main()`? It just re-calls the function even if you break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  Move your global declaration to inside the main function, then this should initialize the status, and then check for status changes.  This can probably be cleaned up a bit (namely the if statement), but it should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import os
import sys
import re
import time


#print status_on.group()
def main():
    global state
    get_current_jack_status = """amixer -c1 contents | grep -A 2 'Headphone Jack'"""
    output = os.popen(get_current_jack_status).read()
    status_on = re.search('values=on', output)
    if (status_on is None and state) or (state is None and status_on):
        state = status_on
        if status_on:
            print "a jack was plugged in"
            os.system("notify-send 'Audio Manager' 'An audio jack was plugged in' -i audacity.png")
        else:
            print "a jack was unplugged"
            os.system("notify-send 'Audio Manager' 'An audio jack was unplugged' -i audacity.png")

get_current_jack_status = """amixer -c1 contents | grep -A 2 'Headphone Jack'"""
output = os.popen(get_current_jack_status).read()
state = re.search('values=on', output)

while True:
        main()
```

Comment: Nope, what I am trying to do is to execute only one time the "notify-send ecc..." command when the status_on == state

Comment: You realize that you're resetting state, and checking it again in the next if statement, right?

Comment: also, as someone mentioned above, you have main wrapped in a while True...

Comment: Check out my edits: i'd recommend using if and elif in stead of two ifs. That might be the root of your problem...

Comment: Yes I know that I've used while true 'cause I have to run this script in background. What I am trying to do is to send a notification when the jack is plugged in or unplugged.

Comment: just try the if/ elif edits...that should do the trick then, I believe.

Comment: Actually, I think I see what you need to do...give me a second and I'll edit my post.

Comment: Check out my updated answer:
1) state is initialized to the current state. 
2) whenever status_on is not state, reset it to state, and indicate the change that happened.

Comment: I've executed the script but when I added (for debugging) a "print 'true' after the "plugged in" case it prints infinite

Answer (score 0):

Then use a variable holding the previous state. And do it like:

```
if status_on == state and previousState!=1:
    print "True"
    state = 1
```

Comment: repeat: i want to send a notification when the headphones jack is plugged in or unplugged

Comment: @Dreamwhite repeat to who? It's not in your question or a comment to this answer.

Comment: Nope, it prints (with the `print "true`) a lot of "true"